# How to convert general time to cronjob time using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cron

A cronjob time syntax such as `"* * * * * *"` followed [cron npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

I want convert time from `"2017-05-09T01:30:00.123Z"` to cron job time format. Have library or method can implement it?

Answer (score 11):

```js
const dateToCron = (date) => {
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const days = date.getDate();
    const months = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const dayOfWeek = date.getDay();

    return `${minutes} ${hours} ${days} ${months} ${dayOfWeek}`;
};

const dateText = '2017-05-09T01:30:00.123Z';
const date = new Date(dateText);

const cron = dateToCron(date);
console.log(cron); //30 5 9 5 2
```

Comment: Although the syntax/format for **CRON is usually 5 values** (with space separation), it can also be 6 or 7 values [see this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111025080042/http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)...It's mentioned inside the earlier [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) Wikipedia article you referenced and I've seen examples deployed in the real world as well.

Comment: The value that is missing is seconds. It is placed just before minutes.

Add the following:


        const seconds = date.getSeconds()    
        return `${seconds} ${minutes} ${hours} ${days} ${months} ${dayOfWeek}`;

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there is any library for it or not. But you can simply implement it using simple date functions.

```
var date=new Date("2017-05-09T01:30:00.123Z");

var mins=date.getMinutes();
//mins variable for the 1st * and so on 
var secs=date.getSeconds();

var dayofmonth=date.getDate();

var month=date.getMonth();

var dayofweek=date.getDay();
```

You can then build a string and use those values in the cron module.